# Probability of drawing of $5$ cards from a deck

Tags: probability, combinations

What is the probability of drawing of $5$ cards from a deck and getting

1) $3$ spades

2) at most $2$ spades

3) at least $3$ spades ?

My attempt is:

1. $(13C3)(49C2)/(52C5)$
2. $(13C0)(52C5)+(13C1)(51C4)+(13C2)(50C3)/(52C5)$
3. $(13C3)(49C2)+(13C4)(48C1)+(13C5)(47C0)/(52C5)$

Comment: The choice of non-spades should be $\binom{39}{n}$ in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

We have 13 spades and 39 non-spades to choose from so the answers should be :

(1)  Choosing (3 spades,2 non spades)

$=(^{13}C_3*^{39}C_2)/(^{52}C_5)$

(2) Choosing (0 spades, 5 non spades),(1 spade, 4 non spades),(2 spades, 3 non spades)

$=(^{13}C_0*^{39}C_5+ ^{13}C_1*^{39}C_4 + ^{13}C_2*^{39}C_3)/(^{52}C_5)$

(3) Choosing (3 spades, 2 non spades),(4 spades, 1 non spade),(5 spades, 0 non spades)

$=(^{13}C_3*^{39}C_2+ ^{13}C_4*^{39}C_1 + ^{13}C_5*^{39}C_0)/(^{52}C_5)$